# iOS APP error in iTunes connect due to not supporting SDK 11?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have submitted an APP for review yesterday and everything went smoothly as they should.

I uploaded my APP from the Application Loader and no errors at all either.

However, when I submitted my APP for review, at the top of my iTunes connect showed this error:

```
The app previews and screenshots for the iPhone 5.8-Inch display won’t appear on the App Store because your binary wasn’t built with the iOS 11 SDK.
```

The APP is still in review but the question I have right now is if they (Apple) will reject it because of that or not?

Comment: did you find a solution/reason for this?